# Change Default Gateway on HP Enclosure C-Class Virtual Connect

Tags: blade-server, hardware

How do I change management default gateway on HP Enclosure C-Class Virtual Connect modules?

Thank you all for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the DG of the VC module itself? It's under EBIPA but choose interconnects instead of devices.

Comment: Thank you fot your answer. Changed under Enclosure Information -> Enclosure Settings -> Enclosure Bays IP Addressing -> Interconnect Bays

but still not working. Do I need VC switch/reboot?

Regards, D.

Comment: what are you changing it from/to, including IP and netmask please, also what version os OA code are you using?

Comment: OA firmware version is 2.41 Feb 24 2009, hardware version B1
DG was 192.168.7.254, now changing to 192.168.7.249 mask 255.255.255.0 but I am sure routing is fine

Thank you

Comment: SOLVED! I had to change default gateway on 'Device Bays' tab and also on 'Interconnect Bays' tab. Previously I changed only on 'Interconnect Bays' 

Thank you for help!